# Is there any extension Order Exchange with same product option or different products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, sales-order, exchange

Is there any Magento 2 extension available for Customer order exchange with same item different Size/color And also Order Exchange with different Products.

reference [link Myntra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4OwI4Ne-T0)

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

The feature is available as RMA (Return Merchandise Authorization) is the process of returning a product to receive a refund, replacement, or exchange during the stipulated time period.

It is in-built feature in Magento Enterprise edition. For community edition there are lots of RMA extension are available. You need to find out the one which best suits your requirements.

For example check [this](https://www.magedelight.com/rma-magento-2.html) extension. Thanks!